# How do I get Facebook comments from Website with Graph API?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

We have been gathering comments from both our Facebook page and from our blog that uses FB's Social Plugins (this allows us to programatically screen the comments for potential spam or inappropriate comments), and it had been going great until last week.  The comments from our Facebook page are still captured without a problem.  For our blog, we had been using the Graph API with a call like this (Python, with 'a' being a list of our blog article URLs):

```
for j in range(length):
    post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=%s" % a[j]
```

The first issue that occurred is that we started getting an error: "An access token is required to request this resource".  So, we created a Facebook application and generated an access token:

```
post_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/comments?id=%s&access_token=OURTOKENHERE" % a[j]
```

Now we get the following error from the API: "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (comments) on node type (URL)"

Any thoughts?  I have seen many examples of code like this in older stackoverflow answers.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#faq_1603507626630008

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for pointer; gets the error to stop, but comments don't seem to be attached to the og_object returned.  e.g. here is URL of a page with comments: [link](https://www.ducttapemarketing.com/blog/how-and-why-i-use-the-facebook-comments-plugin/).  If I call the API from my browser via: [link](https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=og_object{comments,engagement}&id=https://www.ducttapemarketing.com/blog/how-and-why-i-use-the-facebook-comments-plugin/).  I get the engagement expanded but no comments.  Tried using the id to make call to API for comments and that comes back with "data" empty.

Comment: I don't see the FB Comments plugin being used on that URL, only Disqus.